# Бессоюзные сложноподчинённые предложения

Tags: союзы, недопустимая-метка

Бывают ли предложения, которые являются одновременно и бессоюзными и сложноподчинёнными?

Answer (score 1):

**1. Таких предложений нет** (ответ на вопрос)

Все сложные предложения делятся **на три группы**: сложносочиненные (ССП), сложноподчиненные (СПП) и бессоюзные сложные (БСП).

Каждый вид предложения в грамматике имеет свое **определение**, которое связано с наличием **союзов** (сочинительных или подчинительных) или отсутствием их. В каждом случае существует определенная классификация предложений и дается **перечень союзов**.

**2. Почему же возникает такой вопрос?**

Основным **грамматическим значением** сложного предложения являются **смысловые отношения** между его частями, и здесь интересно следующее. Обычно одно и то же значение можно выразить, используя **любой вид** сложного предложения, то есть грамматика **синонимична** в этом плане.

Рассмотрим конкретный пример: нам нужно выразить **причинно-следственные отношения.**

(1) *У нас много работы, **и** сегодня я приехать не смогу* (**ССП**, сочинительный союз И).

*У нас много работы, **и поэтому** сегодня я приехать не смогу* (**ССП,** сочинительный союз И + ***наречие*** поэтому в качестве конкретизатора).

(2) *У нас много работы, **так что** сегодня я приехать не смогу* (**СПП**, подчинительный союз ТАК ЧТО со значением следствия).

(3) *У нас много работы, **поэтому** сегодня я приехать не смогу* (**БСП**, союза нет, наречие в качестве конкретизатора).

*У нас много работы, **соответственно**, сегодня я приехать не смогу* (**БСП**, союза нет, вводное слово в качестве конкретизатора).

**Примечание.** В школьной практике предложения с ***поэтому*** относят к СПП (а не к БСП), считая, что наречие  используется в качестве подчинительного союза. Но в основной грамматике это именно **конкретизатор** значения, а не союз. Он мало чем отличается от других вариантов (наречия, частицы, вводные слова).

**3. Вывод**

Таким образом, **нет предложений,** которые являются одновременно и бессоюзными (БСП) и сложноподчинёнными (СПП). Но **смысловые** отношения в БСП могут выражать **причинно-следственные** отношения, как в СПП.

БСП в этом случае имеют **неоднородный** состав, в отличие от БСП однородного состава с независимыми перечислительными отношениями (то есть без взаимной обусловленности).